# Can't match data from files

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I have code:

```
axios
      .post(
        `login/`,
        data
      )
```

Now I would like search all files to find endpoints by regex expression.

I have regex:

```
const matches = data.match(/([^\s]+).get(?:\([A-z\/`]*\))/g)
```

but it's not working and I haven't found any way to fix it.

Comment: What do you mean by "search all files to find endpoints"? which "files"?

Comment: I found all files from project in folder and subfoders, use fs.readFile and need read endpoint which I used in axios.